# Is it possible to send push notification to a Chrome Web user using Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: google-chrome, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I would like to send notifications to the mobile users of my website (especially *Android/Chrome* users).
I see that Azure Notification Hub handle *Google (GCM)* technology, and i've red this tutorial: [Send push notifications to Chrome apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-chrome-push-notifications-get-started), but can this be done with a simple Web application, and not a *Chrome Application* like in this tutorial?

My application is an ASP.NET MVC 4.5, hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported with Azure Notification Hubs. However, this is in the future roadmap for the product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I find more info about this? Do you have a link?